# Comparing input against .txt and receiving error

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to compare a users input with a .txt file but they never equal. The .txt contains the number 12. When I check to see what the .txt is it prints out as

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='text.txt' encoding='cp1252'>
```

my code is

```
import vlc
a = input("test ")
rflist = open("text.txt", "r")
print(a)
print(rflist)
if rflist == a:
    p = vlc.MediaPlayer('What Sarah Said.mp3')
    p.play()
else:
    print('no')
```

so am i doing something wrong with my open()  or is it something else entirely

Comment: You're not reading the documentation or some tutorial, that's the problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

`rflist.read()` or `f.readline()` is correct.

Read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html) section 7.2

[Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/) is a fantastic book to start Python. take a look at it and you can not put it down.

Answer (score 2):

To print the contents of the file instead of the file object, try

```
print(rflist.read())
```

instead of

```
print(rflist)
```

A file object is not the text contained in the file itself, but rather a wrapper object that facilitates operations on the file, like reading its contents or closing it.